# How to set a value to a label using formula depending on the number of pages the report got printed on ?(Crystal reports)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to set label value to 'Red' if a group in a report is only on one page, and 'Green' if the group requires 2 or more pages. Is there a way to detect if {field1} (group header text) has continued to the next page or ended on the same page? I have been trying this in the formula editor of the label. No luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in function named "InRepeatedGroupHeader". Combined with the Previous function you could detect wether a group is repeated due to a page break or not. CR function with pseudo column name:

```
If 
    InRepeatedGroupHeader 
    And 
    Previous({GroupingField}) = {GroupingField} 
Then // this group header is repeated due to page break 
    'yes' 
Else // this group header is either not repeated or is repeated due to group change
    'no'
```

This may be of use in your case, though it does not allow detecting "groups filling more than one page" on the page a group starts.

Comment: In my case InRepeatedGroupHeader returns true even when the group is not repeated.

Comment: Is there any way to get count of group headers appearing on single page?

Comment: Edited my answer according to your first comment.